# service always starting as root on reboot

Tags: bash, debian, sudo, pid

On reboot, our service script is always starting as root no matter what we try. We need the script to run as a specified user. The PID is getting tied to sudo if we try to use for example sudo -u username or su username Any suggestions?

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          programer
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: programer supervisor process v2.5
# Description:       This file starts stops and monitors the programer process
### END INIT INFO

JAVA_PATH=/usr/bin/programer-java/bin/java
JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
AGENT_PATH=/etc/programer
AGENT=agents.jar
SCRIPT="sudo -u username $JAVA_PATH $JAVA_OPTS -jar $AGENT_PATH/$AGENT"
LOGFILE=$AGENT_PATH/programer.log
PIDFILE=$AGENT_PATH/programer.pid

start() {
  if [ -f $PIDFILE ] && kill -0 $(cat $PIDFILE); then
    printf "   programer service already running...\n"
    return 1
  fi
  printf "   Starting programer service...\n"
  local CMD="$SCRIPT"
  cd $AGENT_PATH
  $CMD > $LOGFILE 2>&1 &
  PID=$!
  echo $PID > $PIDFILE
  chown programer:programer $PIDFILE
  printf "   programer service started...\n"
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    printf "   programer service not running...\n"
    #return 1
  else
    printf "   Stopping programer service...\n"
    kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
    printf "   programer service stopped...\n"
  fi
  # Wait for known process to stop, then look for rogue agents
  sleep 5
  procs=(`ps -ef | grep -e $AGENT | grep -v -e 'grep' -e 'sudo' | awk '{print $1","$2}'`)
  for proc in ${procs[@]}
  do
    pid=`echo $proc | awk -F, '{print $2}'`
    owner=`echo $proc | awk -F, '{print $1}'`
    if [ $owner != "programer" ]; then
       printf "   $0 - WARNING: PID=$pid is owned by $owner!!!! Please use \"sudo kill -9 $pid\" to kill this rogue instance of the programer service\n"
    else
       printf "   $0 - WARNING: Stopping rogue programer service PID=$pid\n"
       kill -15 $pid
    fi
  done
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    sleep 3
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: basename $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: What do you mean "The PID is getting tied to sudo"? You need to write the pidfile out as part of the script/etc. you run under sudo and not outside of that.

Comment: Ok I posted the entire service file now

Comment: `"The PID is getting tied to sudo"` because the process running in background is the `sudo`  command, not the process launched by `sudo`. That `sudo` process belongs to `root`; its child process belongs to `username`, does it not?

Comment: You should use your PID variable to find out the PID of the child process; for instance, using the `ps` command: `ps -o pid= --ppid "$PID"`

Comment: Yes exactly. We did not know how to get the process ID of the child.

Comment: Write the pid file in the command you give to sudo if you want that. But why do you want that? The sudo stays running the whole time too doesn't it so isn't that what you want to kill/check for/etc.?

Comment: All we are trying to do is run the process as the processes defined username, but since the service script is run as root on start, when it creates the PID file for the process, the file is owned by root so it messes everything up. We need the process started by "username" and the PID file created (well owned) by that username too. Not root.

Comment: Yup so you are totally right Etan. I think we are going to abandon this method completely. I might look into doing chroot.

Answer (score 0):

check out `start-stop-daemon` (part of the `dpkg` package, so already installed on your system), a utility that was written exactly for your kind of problems.

it takes care of

- starting/stopping
- backgrounding
- changing the effective user
- writing PID-files